# How should an employer respond to a government policy requiring abortion coverage?

Tags: halacha, employment, current-events, politics-government

There is a recent [controversy](http://www.economist.com/node/21547241) in the United States regarding whether the Federal government can compel employers, including religious employers, to pay for contraception.  Although this may not be objectionable to most religious Jews, who do not consider contraception to be equivalent to abortion, Catholics (who *do* consider it to be abortion) have objected to the new law rather vociferously.

What if some future policy would require employers to pay for actual abortions, by whatever definition would be considered as prohibited halachically?

How would a religious Jewish employer be required, by Jewish law, to respond to such a law?  Is it permissible to subsidize someone else's transgression of such a grave prohibition?  If such a law were to come into effect, would a Jewish school be required to either violate the law or shut down the school?

Comment: It's not clear that halacha considers abortion to be murder.  In a few cases, (i.e. to save the life of the mother), abortion is required.  In other cases, (i.e. the baby will be born with Tay-Sachs, lo aleinu) abortion may be permitted.  In other, more general cases, abortion might be forbidden, but not quite the same thing as murder.  Every potential abortion case is highly individualized, and for this reason, one cannot make a blanket statement on the status of abortion in halacha.

Comment: @Will my question is not intended to start a debate about abortions.  It is about the appropriate response to government policies that require one to pay for others' doing highly objectionable things.  Abortion is just an example of how that would come up in practice.

Comment: @TalFishman you wrote in the quesiton, "Is it permissible to pay for what is halachically considered murder?"  That is a presupposition of your question, and I am challenging it.

Comment: @Will as I said, you are missing the point of the question.  If you find it so distracting, then I will modify the question.

Comment: @TalFishman I knew what the point of the question was.  Asking a question about paying for murder will get a different answer than asking about paying for something that's assur, but not murder.  The "givens" in a question really do make a difference.

Comment: @Will, I seem to recall that abortion does count as killing as a _mitzvas b'ne Noach_ (though does not count as killing as a _mitzva_ for Jews); since most abortionists are gentiles, the original wording may well be valid. (See also [_Rambam_, _M'lachim_ 9:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=83&perek=9&halocha=4&hilite=).)

Comment: @msh210 so I guess the question is, does "Chai Bahem" apply to Noahides.  I've always assumed it does, but I have no source for it.  (Contrast with some Christian groups, who are against all abortions, with no exceptions for live-saving medical intervention)

Comment: Barry [points out](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14295/2) an important distinction: The policy at issue does not require employers to pay for any particular medical care; it requires them to subsidize insurance that, in turn, is obligated to cover various types of care. It'd probably be worth reflecting this distinction in the question.

Comment: @Will The gemara [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=74b&format=pdf) towards the bottom debates if gentiles are obligated and seems to conclude that they are not.

Comment: @Will my original thought behind including the murder line was only, as msh210 points out, to make it clear that this is something Jewish law prohibits gentiles from doing, as well (under certain circumstances), and that it is a very serious issur.

Comment: I highly suggest you change this question to ask about Euthanasia, or some other clear cut case of "murder" :)

Comment: @avi While my question is a hypothetical, the scary part is that the way social trends have gone over the last few decades I could conceive of it becoming a reality in my life time.  Not so for insurer-subsidized euthanasia.

Comment: Tal, I don't understand why you are bringing the discussion back from a generalized Issur with the focus in the question being on the employer, to a specific (controversial) issue that may or may not be Asur depending on the case and forcing answers to address a myriad of variables unrelated to the employer.

Comment: @TalFishman Insurer subsidized euthanasia is a real possibility. There are many groups fighting for such rights.  Especially for the elderly and cancer patients.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An employer is paying the premiums on an employee's insurance policy, which will then pay the medical expenses incurred by the employee committing a halachically-unacceptable act. With respect to "Lifnei Iver" or "placing a stumbling block before the blind," there are multiple mitigating factors:

1. The prohibited act may never happen. The employee may never need to get an abortion.
2. Even if the insurance policy didn't cover it, the employee may have paid for the abortion herself (see A"Z 6b re: "two sides of the river").
3. If the employer wouldn't pay for the premiums, the employee can still obtain employment by another employer who will pay for it.
4. It is "lifnei dLifnei," or it is causing one to stumble by causing another to stumble. This is not prohibited by Lifnei Iver (see A"Z 14a, and Tos. A"Z 15b).

With respect to "mesaya" or "facilitating sin", consider the payment of wages themselves. Say the employer knows that the employee will use the money for illicit acts. May the employer pay her wages? It doesn't seem logical that this should be considered "facilitating sin". It is too indirect.

Comment: Barry, I think you hit the nail on the head here. From a strict halachic perspective of "sin facilitation", we have more than ample wiggle room. There may still be Jews opposed on principle because of precedent on First Ammendment interpretation, but that's way, way beyond a technical halachic concern.

Comment: Good points, all of them, but the employer may be paying more directly for these abortions than you realize.  First off, the premiums will rise immediately once abortion is covered, so the employer is paying directly for the potential provision of a prohibited service.  Second, many employer schemes base one year's premiums on the previous year's costs, so that higher costs in one year due to coverage of abortions feeds directly into the employer's premiums the following year.

Comment: @Shalom, Jews would obviously be opposed to such a law even if they weren't required to shut down to avoid paying for it. From a Jewish perspective, one won't want to be forced to support something forbidden, because its wrong, even if technically not a "lifnei iver".

Comment: @TalFishman You are ignoring Barry's point altogether. Even if the employer is paying for the premium, he is not paying for the abortion. Even if he were paying the employee directly for the abortion itself, this is still not necessarily ([see pg 38, footnote 19, R' Breitowitz (9th pg of the PDF)](http://www.jofa.org/pdf/uploaded/1518-OWUK0769.pdf)) direct Lifnei 'Iver.  The worst case would be the employer paying the doctor directly, but that is not the case here.

Comment: @ArielK, The previous version of this question had a title that seemed to be about public policy, but questions in the body about specific reactions by employers. I've edited the title to match the body. Given that, Barry's approach regarding what would be permitted or prohibited in the context of the hypothetical law in consideration is to the point.

Comment: +1. As always, sources for your specific claims (e.g., that _lifne iver_ is mitigated when the anticipated event may never happen, that _lifne d'lifne_ is permitted, and that the sinner can sin by other means if not thus assisted) would be most valuable.